# How to save the settings in the app when the user changes the notification settings?

Tags: ios, notifications, swift3

I implemented push notifications in the AppDelegate.swift class in FCM. Notifications is great, but how do I save the settings in the app when the user changes the notifications settings?

Comment: you want to know that user changed the APNS is ON or OFF in settings

Comment: Notification is managed by backhand you have to pass flags to server for you want push or not from your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check notification settings by calling notification delegate method

```
 let notificationCenter = AppDelegate().getNotificationCenter()
    notificationCenter.getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: { (setting) in
          if(setting.authorizationStatus == .denied){
       })
     }
```

Public classes for getting notification.

> ```
> public static var badge: UNAuthorizationOptions { get }
>
> public static var sound: UNAuthorizationOptions { get }
>
> public static var alert: UNAuthorizationOptions { get }
>
> public static var carPlay: UNAuthorizationOptions { get }
> ```

for more : https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unauthorizationoptions

let me know is it helpful or not?

Comment: Thank you. Can you show me a code example that turns a sound into a vibration and an example that turns a sound off?

Comment: I've updated some more reference. Let me know u got your answer or not. Thanks,